# D-Bus D-Feet Send Dictionary of String,Variants in Python Syntax

Tags: python, dictionary, dbus

I'm trying to use D-Feet to send D-Bus commands for ConnMan. D-Feet says all Parameters should be in "Python Syntax".

The D-Bus method is described by D-Bus as this:

```
ConnectProvider(Dict of {String,Variant} provider) => (Object Path path)
```

I've tried each of these ( Python dictionaries ):

```
{u'Type': u'wifi', u'Mode': u'managed', u'SSID': u'testSSID', u'Security': u'WPA', u'Passphrase': u'test'}
{'Type': 'wifi', 'Mode': 'managed', 'SSID': 'testSSID', 'Security': 'WPA', 'Passphrase': 'test'}
{"Type": "wifi", "Mode": "managed", "SSID": "testSSID", "Security": "WPA", "Passphrase": "test"}
{"Type":__import__('dbus').String("wifi", variant_level=1),"Mode":__import__('dbus').String("managed", variant_level=1),"SSID":__import__('dbus').String("testSSID", variant_level=1),"Security":__import__('dbus').String("WPA", variant_level=1),"Passphrase":__import__('dbus').String("test", variant_level=1)}
```

But I keep getting the error 'Invalid Arguments':

[image]

I have dbus-monitor --system running so I can view anything happening on the system bus but when I click 'Execute' nothing is actually sent to the bus. I immediately get the error so I am assuming D-Feet is saying the format of the input is incorrect.

What am I doing wrong? How can I send this command? Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I got this to work in D-Feet as "Method input" to a method that takes an a{sv}:

```
{"key": __import__('gi.repository.GLib', globals(), locals(), ['Variant']).Variant("s", "value")}
```

Answer (score 3):

With d-feet 0.3.6, there is a way without explicitly importing GLib.
It might be useful for some future readers.

For methods with an argument signature:

- a{sv} which is Dict of {String,Variant}

Here is the input format:

```
{<key> : GLib.Variant(<type-code>, <value>)}
```

Some examples with multiple key-value pairs:

```
{"key1" : GLib.Variant("s", "string value"),
 "key2" : GLib.Variant("b", False),
 "key3" : GLib.Variant("(di)", (1.2, 42))
}
```

- The key1's value is a variant containing a string value
- The key2's value is a variant containing a boolean value
- The key3's value is a variant containing a struct of (double, int32)